# Where is the tableList becoming null? and Why?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am implementing an Adapter to take List and Hashmap and turn them into headers and children respectively for an Expandable ListView. In the constructor's Log statements it is showing that the values are being transferred to the local list successfully. But then it suddenly turns null.

I can't pinpoint what went wrong and where. Please help.

Here is my code for the Adapter class:

```
class ExpandableListViewAdapterDemo extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

Context context = null;
private List<String> headersList;//semester's name and year
private HashMap<String, List<String>> tableList;//course names with its grades and gpa

static final String TAG = "**Adapter Demo**";

ExpandableListViewAdapterDemo(Context context, List<String> list,
                              HashMap<String, List<String>> hashMap){
    this.context = context;
    headersList = list;
    tableList = hashMap;
    Log.e(TAG, "hashmap list value = "+hashMap.get("Spring 2016"));
    Log.e(TAG, "initial table list value = "+tableList.get("Spring 2016"));
    printMap(tableList);
    //printAll();
    Log.e(TAG, "groupCount = "+getGroupCount());

}

void printAll(){
    Log.e(TAG, "headers count = "+headersList.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < headersList.size() ; i++) {
        Log.e(TAG, "header at i="+i+" ,"+headersList.get(i));
    }
    printMap(tableList);
}

private static void printMap(HashMap mp) {
    Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        HashMap.Entry pair = (HashMap.Entry)it.next();
        Log.e(TAG, "#253 : "+pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
        it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
    }
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    Log.e(TAG, "#299 : table list value = "+tableList.get("Spring 2016"));
    return headersList.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
    //Log.e(TAG, "at i="+i+" "+headersList.get(i));
    int returns = 0;
    Log.e(TAG, "#307 : table list value = "+tableList.get("Spring 2016"));
    if (tableList.get(headersList.get(i)) != null)
        returns = tableList.get(headersList.get(i)).size();
    else
        Log.e(TAG, "tableList is null");
    Log.e(TAG, "details size = "+returns);
    Log.e(TAG, "group count = "+getGroupCount());
    int tosubtract = 2 * getGroupCount();
    if (returns>tosubtract)
        returns = returns - tosubtract - 2;
    Log.e(TAG, "child count returns = "+String.valueOf(returns) );
    return i;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int i) {
    Log.e(TAG, "#323 : table list value = "+tableList.get("Spring 2016"));
    return headersList.get(i);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
    Log.e(TAG, "#329 : table list value = "+tableList.get("Spring 2016"));
    return tableList.get(headersList.get(i)).get(i1);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int i) {
    Log.e(TAG, "#335 : table list value = "+tableList.get("Spring 2016"));
    return i;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
    Log.e(TAG, "#340 : table list value = "+tableList.get("Spring 2016"));
    return i1;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    Log.e(TAG, "#347 : table list value = "+tableList.get("Spring 2016"));
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    Log.e(TAG, "#353 : table list value = "+tableList.get("Spring 2016"));
    String semesterTitle = (String) getGroup(i);
    if (view == null){
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inf.inflate(R.layout.previous_semesters_result_list_headers, null);
    }

    TextView semesterName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.semester_name);
    semesterName.setText(semesterTitle);
    return view;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    Log.e(TAG, "#367 : table list value = "+tableList.get("Spring 2016"));
    String courseIdTitle = (String) getChild(i, i1);
    String gpa = (String) getChild(i, i1+getChildrenCount(i));//previously i1+4
    String grade = (String) getChild(i, i1+getChildrenCount(i)+getChildrenCount(i));
    if (view == null){
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inf.inflate(R.layout.previous_semesters_results_list_child, null);
    }
    TextView courseIdValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.course_id_column_value);
    courseIdValue.setText(courseIdTitle);
    TextView gradeValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.grade_column_value);
    gradeValue.setText(grade);
    TextView gpaValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gpa_column_value);
    gpaValue.setText(gpa);
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
    Log.e(TAG, "#386 : table list value = "+tableList.get("Spring 2016"));
    return true;
}
}
```

Here is my Log : 
[image]

Comment: It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger. Please help yourself to some complementary debugging techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You removed the item while printing the map,

```
it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
```

Just remove this it will work fine.

```
private static void printMap(HashMap mp) {
    Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        HashMap.Entry pair = (HashMap.Entry)it.next();
        Log.e(TAG, "#253 : "+pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
        //it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your method `printMap()`, the last statement in the `while` block is

```
 it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
```

This statement may not cause an `Exception` but it removes the current entry from the `HashMap`. So after executing

```
printMap(tableList);
```

in the `Constructor` of `ExpandableListViewAdapterDemo`, the *tableList* will be empty.